# Understanding media queries

Tags: html, css

so i’m trying to make my non responsive website www.expanse.co.in responsive however just can’t make it look the same for all/most mobile phones and screen sizes .. from what I learned on searching online i added media queries for every resolution where the site seemed to break but now anytime I add another it seems to break previous how can I make it responsive for all resolutions.?
eg of some of the media queries i added but adding more media queries like this will break previous ones so is there any way for it to work on all resolutions

```
/*iphone 6/7/8 */
        @media only screen 
          and (min-device-width: 375px) 
          and (max-device-width: 667px) 
          and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
          and (orientation: portrait) { 

              #bot {
                  margin-top: 500px;
                  height: 500px;
              }
              .subfield {
                  margin-top: 240%;
                  margin-left: 20%;
              }
              .iconBar {
                padding-top: 250%;
                margin-left: 22%;
            }
            #botText {
                margin-top: 150%;
                padding-left: 34%;
                font-size: 32px;
            }
            #botText2 {
                margin-top: 164%;
                font-size: 14px;
            }

            }
/*iphone 5/5c/5s/se */
        @media only screen 
              and (min-device-width: 320px) 
              and (max-device-width: 568px)
              and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
              and (orientation: portrait) {
                #bot {
                  margin-top: 500px;
                  height: 570px;
              }
              .subfield {
                  margin-top: 296%;
                  margin-left: 20%;
              }
              .iconBar {
                padding-top: 312%;
                margin-left: 20%;
            }
            #botText {
                margin-top: 170%;
                padding-left: 34%;
                font-size: 32px;
            }
            #botText2 {
                margin-top: 192%;
                font-size: 14px;
            }
            }
```

Comment: Please add your media query codes.

Comment: ive edited and added media queries ,it may seem out of context however my question is adding more media queries like this will break previous ones so is there any way for it to work on all resolutions ?

Answer (score 1):

This will make your `body` 100 pixels wide on any screen that has a width of **EQUAL OR GREATER** than 768 pixels.

```
 @media (min-width: 768px) {
     body {
         width:100px;
    }
}
```

This will make your `body` 100 pixels wide on any screen that has a width of **EQUAL OR LESSER** than 768 pixels.

```
 @media (max-width: 768px) {
     body {
         width:100px;
    }
}
```

Not one size fits all with styles, and how you handled your styles in your base rules will determine how difficult it may be to create proper media queries. [You can use templates](http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/2013/06/responsive-media-queries-css.html) to help understand what screens will be used, but as a whole you should try and make your elements as fluid as possible from the start.

Use your browser of choice's dev tools to inspect your elements, and even select common screen sizes from the drop down menu in Chrome's Dev Tools.

[image]

[appendTo puts together a decent guide](https://appendto.com/2016/11/a-simple-guide-to-css-media-queries/) for how to structure your media queries and spacing your breakpoints, noting that having breakpoints for heights/widths that are so close together will leave less than desirable effects at times.

As well, determining your approach first will save you a ton of hassle. [**Mobile First** or **Desktop First**](http://www.the-haystack.com/2015/12/23/choosing-between-min-and-max-width/). *Mobile First* is going to utilize minimum widths to design from small to bigger, and *Desktop First* is obviously the opposing. Its good to figure this out prior to starting your project, but you don't necessarily have to commit to one or the other permanently, just on a project basis. You can decide by thinking about where your audience will most use your project.

Comment: yes thank you i've been using chrome's developer tools to test the sizes however usually adding for one media query breaks some of the other ones and also i try to use % instead of using pixel values so it would auto adjust in every resolution but it still seems to break in one resolution or the other or maybe in landscape modes in some phones etc

Comment: Check out the template guide I linked in my answer. It'll help a lot with developing your own scope for your particular style.

Comment: I've added some additional resources in there as well. Let me know if anything is unclear!

Comment: You media query interpretation is faulty because both interpretations miss out on the given pixel value being **included**. Correct would be either ***OVER** 767 pixels* or *greater or equals 768 pixels*.

Comment: @connexo yeah you're absolutely right. I'll edit this in.

Comment: It would be *equal or less than*, not *lesser*.

Answer (score 0):

Make your life better with a ‘mobile-first’ approach by using (min-width) rules, starting from mobile and going up, or the other way around by using (max-width) rules.
Do not mix them together as that generates logic which is hard and unpleasant to write.
Think about the approach you prefer and then apply it, changing the viewport width constantly and trying to manipulate code on the go, a not-working approach for responsive design.

Comment: yes I realized that having one approach before starting to develop is better however though my only trying to convert a non responsive one is almost impossible it seems without breaking some of the resolutions or phones ?